# Github Pages doesn't publish

Tags: html, github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have an index.html and everything but it won't publish. Repo here:
https://github.com/NNMGStudios/nnmgstudios.github.io 
It's just a Bootstrap Theme for now and it runs fine locally.

Comment: Have you configured github to enable pages?

Comment: also it takes some time from commit to publishing to take place

Answer (score 0):

Your repo's name should be **nnmg-studios.github.io**, not **nnmgstudios.github.io**, so it matches your username.

Right now, your site can be accessed at `nnmg-studios.github.io/nnmgstudios.github.io`, but renaming your repo will make it accessible at `nnmg-studios.github.io`.